# Iterating a JSONObject doesn't fill the spinner

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-spinner

I have an issue that i unable to understand i.e when i make an http request i get following JSONObject as response. I have to loop-iterate every keys, take the data that i need, build them in an object and fill the spinner, but i think there is something wrong in the loop or i don't know, cause when i take every object, alone without a loop, all work fine, 
when i loop to build object and add to array list dynamically it don't work:

```
{
    "Conteggio": 2,
    "0": {
        "Distributore Information": {
            "id_distributore": "1",
            "NomeDistributore": "Colonnina 0",
            "litriiniziocolonna": "444",
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "Distributore Information": {
            "id_distributore": "2",
            "NomeDistributore": "Colonnina 1",
            "litriiniziocolonna": "555",
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it's wrong loop through a JSONObject but i cant change this JSON.

Here the android code code:

```
    private void getInfoColonnina(){
    String url = "https://icantshowtheurlbutitworkfine_module.json";
    final SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences("loginPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor myPreff = myPref.edit();

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            List<DistrBean> distrBeansList = new ArrayList<>();

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Iterator keys = jsonObject.keys();

                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    Object key = keys.next();
                    JSONObject value = jsonObject.getJSONObject((String) key);
                    JSONObject info = value.getJSONObject("Distributore Information");
                    String LitriColonnina1 = info.getString("litriiniziocolonna");
                    String NomeDistributore1 = info.getString("NomeDistributore");
                    String id_distributore1 = info.getString("id_distributore");

                    DistrBean distrBean = new DistrBean();

                    distrBean.setLitriColonnina(LitriColonnina1);
                    distrBean.setNomeDistributore(NomeDistributore1);
                    distrBean.setIdDistributore(id_distributore1);

                    distrBeansList.add(distrBean);

                }

                ArrayAdapter<DistrBean> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DistrBean>(InizioTurnoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, distrBeansList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        DistrBean distrBean = (DistrBean) adapterView.getSelectedItem();
                        getSelectedDistr(distrBean);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(InizioTurnoActivity.this, "CHIAMATA INFOCOLONNINA FALLITA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void getSelectedDistr(DistrBean v){
        DistrBean distrBean = (DistrBean) spinner.getSelectedItem();
        setDistrData(distrBean);
    }

    private void setDistrData(DistrBean distrBean){
        String name = distrBean.getNomeDistributore();
        String litri = distrBean.getLitriColonnina();
        String id = distrBean.getIdDistributore();

        tvProgressivo.setText(litri);
        tvColonnina.setText(name);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Hai selezionato " + name +  "che ha litri: " + litri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Can you guys help me? thank you in advance!

Comment: Add some breakpoints and check if your list is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

your json is not valid

```
{
    "Conteggio": 2,
    "0": {
        "Distributore Information": {
            "id_distributore": "1",
            "NomeDistributore": "Colonnina 0",
            "litriiniziocolonna": "444", //this line
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "Distributore Information": {
            "id_distributore": "2",
            "NomeDistributore": "Colonnina 1",
            "litriiniziocolonna": "555", //this line
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test your rest api on postman before integrating it in android app and use Gson library, response model to handle all json response. Gson library automatically parse data according to your model so you dont need to get data by specifying individual key.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your parsing algorithm has issue.

```
Iterator keys = jsonObject.keys();
```

-> Conteggio, 0, 1
So you should skip one.